# User Login Destination | to his first submission | Webforms

Tags: webforms, users

i have a career form built with webforms ; I need the users to go back to their first submission when they come back to the site again .

Login Destinations | can help me with that . but it will send only to a specific URL . where in my case every user have its own submission and i want him to return back to it in Edit mode when he/she logins again .

any clues /
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve using [hook_user_login()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7) function.

```
function mymodule_user_login(&$edit, $account)
{
  // Your logic will set $redirection to the desired location.
  // Get the logic and fetch where do you want to redirect.
  // Here i am redirecting to node 34. You can fetch your own webform submission path
  // where do you want to redirect. 
  // Fetch the submission of done by the current users. by using http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/webform_get_submissions/7 function
  $redirection = 'node/34';


// Unless there is already a redirection going, or the user is trying to reset his password, we redirect to $redirection.
  if (empty($_GET['destination'])
    && !is_null($redirection)
    && (!isset($_POST['form_id']) || $_POST['form_id'] != 'user_pass_reset'))
  {
    $_GET['destination'] = $redirection; // Should we use $edit['redirect'] instead..?
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks mohit , but i need each user to go to its own form (edit mode) which he submitted earlier .

Comment: you can find the webform submissions of the logged in users and then you can redirect it to respective page.

Comment: where should i be altering this hook function ? in my template.php ?

Comment: in template.php you can also write, but create a simple module. in the .module file of module write the MODULENAME_user_login() function.